Why can't I drag the measure to X-axis
I have created a measure:
```
TotalWeeksPerIssue = SUMX(
    VALUES('Query2'[name]),
    SUM('Query2'[weeks_in_work])
)
```

I want to use it to visualize bar chart on X-axis. But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?
I'm trying to calculate the total number of weeks for each task and then determine how many times each total occurred.
Example data and result:



name
weeks_in_work
status




Issue1
1
in work


Issue1
2
stopped


Issue2
3
in work


Issue2
3
in work


Issue3
4
stopped


Issue3
5
in work



Then, I need to count sum for each name:



name
TotalWeeks




Issue1
3


Issue2
6


Issue3
9



and then the amount of each
totalweek:
3 - 1
6 - 1
9 - 1
I tried to create a measure to sum the weeks for each task:
TotalWeeksPerIssue = SUMX(
    VALUES('Query2'[name]),
    SUM('Query2'[weeks_in_work])
)

and then:
CountOfTotalWeeks = COUNTROWS(
    SUMMARIZE(
        'Query2',
        'Query2'[name],
        "TotalWeeks", SUM('Query2'[weeks_in_work])
    )
)

Making a bar chart I can't drag the TotalWeeksPerIssue measure to the X-axis.
the problem is that I also have a column status which I have to add to the filter because sometimes I need to count sum for all statuses and sometimes only for one.
That's the reason why I can't create an extra table.
How can I visualize this using measures?

Can you please provide more information so we can replicate this question? What kind of visual are you using? What column is on your other axis? What is some of the data you are using?

@NickA added extra information

This is the closest I am able to get you to your desired result:

Create Total Weeks measure.
Create Occurrence measure.
Create Bar Chart for name column and Total Weeks measure.
Create Table for name, TotalWeeks, and Occurrence that shows the occurrences of the total weeks.
Add status slicer.
Testing the Visuals

1. Create Total Weeks measure.
TotalWeeks = SUM(Query2[weeks_in_work])

2. Create Occurrence measure.
Occurrence = 
VAR table1 =
    SUMMARIZE ( ALL(Query2), Query2[name], "weekCount", [TotalWeeks] )
VAR thisName =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Query2[name] )
VAR fil =  FILTER( table1, [name] = thisName  ) 
VAR thisWeek =
    //CALCULATE ( MINX ( table1, [weekCount] ), FILTER ( table1, [name] = thisName ) )
    MINX(FILTER( table1, [name] = thisName  ), [weekCount])
    
VAR filWeeks =
    FILTER ( table1, [weekCount] = thisWeek )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS ( filWeeks )

3. Create Bar Chart for name column and Total Weeks measure.

4. Create Table for name, TotalWeeks, and Occurrence that shows the occurrences of the total weeks.

5. Add status slicer.

6. Testing the Visuals
All the visuals together:

Selecting a slicer value:


thanks a lot for this guide. Now I'm trying to create a bar chart with TotalWeeks on X-axis and Occurence on Y-axis,but still TotalWeeks doesn't drag to X-axis :(

Unfortunately, Occurrence and TotalWeeks can only be used in the bottom right table along with name. Both of those measures require name to function properly. Therefore, cannot be used in a bar chart together.

Yes, I have already realized it. But thank you very much for helping!
